# How to prove $G_{A^*}\supseteq (V G_A)^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, spectral-theory

If $A:D\subset H \rightarrow H$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is a unbounded densely defined operator. Then its adjoint exists and

$$\left\langle \begin{pmatrix}x \\ Ax \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y \\ A^*y \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle=0$$

Where $V:= \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is a unitary operator on $H\times H$.

Therefore $G_{A^*}\subseteq (V G_A)^\perp$.

How to prove  $G_{A^*}\supseteq (V G_A)^\perp$?

Here $G_A$ and $G_{A^*}$ denote the graph of $A$ and $A^*$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: nothing, I stuck.

Comment: If you disregard the use of $E^*$ and $F^*$ (it's a more general definition of adjoint operators, and for Hilbert spaces you can just use the identification $H^* \simeq H$), the body of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4356791/1104384) should answer your question.